# Exception of type java.util.NoSuchElementException due to nextInt()

Tags: java, eclipse, java.util.scanner

I'm have 2 classes namely, MyClient and CustomerUserInterface.
The MyClient class has a main method in which I call methods of CustomerUserInterface.

**MyClient**

```
    public class MyClient {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
    CustomerUserInterface customerUserInterface = new CustomerUserInterfaceImpl();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    customerUserInterface.registerLoginMenu();
    int choice = scan.nextInt();
    customerUserInterface.performOperationsOnRegisterLoginMenu(choice);
        }
    }
```

**CustomerUserInterface**

```
public class CustomerUserInterfaceImpl implements CustomerUserInterface {

private CustomerBL customerBl;
private ProductInterface productInterface;

public CustomerUserInterfaceImpl() {
    customerBl = new CustomerBLImpl();
    productInterface = new ProductInterfaceImpl();
}

@Override
public void registerLoginMenu() {
    System.out.println("1. Register");
    System.out.println("2. Login");
    System.out.println("3. Exit");
}

@Override
public void register() {
    Customer customer = CustomerInputHelper.inputCustomer();
    boolean status=false;
    try {
        status = customerBl.registerUser(customer);
    }catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(status) {
        System.out.println("Register Success");
        login();
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Register Unsuccessful");
        registerLoginMenu();
    }
}

@Override
public void login() {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Boolean status=false;
    System.out.println("Enter customerID : ");      
    int id = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter password : ");
    String pwd = scan.next();
    try {
        status = customerBl.verifyUser(id, pwd);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(status) {
        productInterface.afterLoginMenu();
        System.out.println("Enter choice : ");
        int choice = scan.nextInt();
        Customer customer = null;
        try {
            customer = customerBl.getCustomer(id);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        productInterface.performOperationsOnAfterLoginMenu(choice,customer);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Login failed");
        registerLoginMenu();
    }
    scan.close();
}

@Override
public void performOperationsOnRegisterLoginMenu(int choice) {
    switch(choice) {
    case 1:
        register();
        break;
    case 2:
        login();
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("Good Bye ! Have a Nice Day!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
}
```

The problem I'm facing is that I get an error in login() method after my first System.out line, i.e.,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
```

The register calls the login method after successful registration but just after the login method call I get the above error.

I don't understand the problem as the user gets registered but the error is shown just after the login method is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are registering Scanner on system.in twice, once in MyClient:

```
public class MyClient {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
```

and once in CustomerUserInterface login method:

```
@Override
public void login() {
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
```

that will not work, as the first scanner already had the System.in stream.

You need to use same instance of scanner throughout your program.

Answer (score 0):

Try slowing your program down to accept the input before using the input variable for in a function call.

That is: verify that the “choice” is not holding any nonsensical value.

That should help.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) of the `Scanner` class tells you that the `NoSuchElementException` is thrown if the input stream is exhausted. Therefore I'd assume, that the input stream is closed for some reason.

How do you run your code? Through an IDE or just with a `java MyClient` call on the command line? Maybe there lays your error.

If you run the following code it should repeat your input. If this does not work you are calling your code in the wrong way.

```java
public class MyClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(sc.nextInt());
    }
}
```